# How can I show greetings like Good Moring, afternoon or evening base on users time in flutter

Tags: date, flutter, dart, time

I want to greet user when they visit my app

I have tried using TimeOfDay but it isn't working.

```
TimeOfDay now = TimeOfDay.now();

  greetings(String greeting){
    var greeting = now;
    if(greeting <= '11: 59'){
      return 'Morning';
    } else if (greeting > '11:59' && <= '16:59'){
      return 'Afternoon';
    } else if (greeting > '16:59' && <= '23:59'){
      return 'Afternoon';
    } else {
      return 'Morning';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try using `DateTime.now()`, for example:

```
String greeting() {
  var hour = DateTime.now().hour;
  if (hour < 12) {
    return 'Morning';
  }
  if (hour < 17) {
    return 'Afternoon';
  }
  return 'Evening';
}
```

Comment: Excellent response. Thanks very much.

Comment: The best and simplest answer out there. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are using `TimeOfDay` in wrong way. Your code should work if you use it properly.

```
String greetings(){
  final hour = TimeOfDay.now().hour;

  if(hour <= 12){
    return 'Morning';
  } else if (hour <= 17){
    return 'Afternoon';
  }
  return 'Evening';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TimeOfDay.now().period; 
// This will return DayPeriod.am or DayPeriod.pm, you can show the greeting message accordingly
```

Link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay/period.html

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  TimeOfDay day = TimeOfDay.now();
  switch(day.period){
    case DayPeriod.am: print('its morning');
      break;
    case DayPeriod.pm: print('its evening/night');
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great but I would use a switch on the enum itself, `day.period`, instead of a string.

Comment: @MJ12358 Yeah you are right! "toString()" is unnecessary here. I changed it!

Comment: 12pm is not evening